# function call does not return value for the first time

Tags: node.js, rest

I have created function to fetch the response from third party rest api, however when i call it from the other js file it does not return value for the first time. if i hit it again then it fetches the value.

i have tried using callback, async/awit, request-promise to address the issue but unable to resolve.

index.js

```
const express = require('express');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const reqHand = require("./request-handler");

var strAssigneeID = "";

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

//var routes = require('./routes.js')(app);

app.get("/", function(req, res) {

    res.send("Hello World!");

});

app.get("/isValidUser", function(req, res){
    strAssigneeID = reqHand.getAssigneeID('fred.luddy');
    console.log('In route: ' + strAssigneeID);
    res.send(strAssigneeID);
});

app.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('Server is running on port: 8080')
});
```

request-handler.js

```
const express = require("express");
const request = require("request");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var retBody = "";

module.exports = {
    getAssigneeID: function(username) {
        var options = {
            baseUrl: 'www.something.com',
            method: 'GET',
            uri: '/api/test/',
            json: true,
            headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Request'
        },
        auth: {
            'user': 'user',
            'pass': 'password',
            sendImmediately: true
        }
    };

    request(options, function(err, ressponse, body) {
        if(!err && ressponse.statusCode==200) {
            retBody = body;
        } else {
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
        }
    });
    console.log('In Request:' + retBody);
    return (retBody);
}
}
```

It should fetch the data everytime and not after first try.

Answer (score 0):

I think because you misspelled the `response` word as `ressponse`

```
request(options, function(err, ressponse, body) 
// Correct your spelling of response
{
        if(!err && ressponse.statusCode==200) {
            retBody = body;
        } else {
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! for highlighting the same however, upon fixing that i am still getting the same output. I think it is to do something with async nature of JS.

Answer (score 0):

The return statement containing `retBody` is executing before the request is returning a response, since the return statement is outside the callback function. Move the return statement as indicated in the snippet below, and it should work

```
    request(options, function(err, ressponse, body) {
        if(!err && ressponse.statusCode==200) {
            retBody = body;
            // Move the return here
            console.log('In Request:' + retBody);
            return (retBody);
        } else {
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
        }
    });
    console.log('In Request:' + retBody);
    // return (retBody); <<<< Move this to inside the if statement.
```